# Automatic Email Script/Program for fictional e-store C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, email

This is a fictional email sending program for a e-store I've done for practice purposes. EmailSenderProgram is a program sending emails to customers. Currently it sends two types of email: "welcome" and "please come back" email. It's supposed to run daily and write a debug log each day if it worked or not. Would love some rice and roses where is needed. This is the entire code.

First we have the main method.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Sender.Errors.Clear();
    Sender.SendWelcomeEmails();
    SendingMail.SendComeBackEmail("Thisisavouchercode");
    if (sender.Errors.Any())
        Console.WriteLine("All mails are sent, I hope...");
}
```

Following with the DataLayerClass

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDatetime { get; set; }
}

class DataLayer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Mockup method for all customers
    /// </summary>
    public static List<Customer> ListCustomers()
    {
        return new List<Customer>()
                   {
                       new Customer(){Email = "mail1@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-7)}, 
                       new Customer(){Email = "mail2@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)}, 
                       new Customer(){Email = "mail3@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)}, 
                       new Customer(){Email = "mail4@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)}, 
                       new Customer(){Email = "mail5@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)},
                       new Customer(){Email = "mail6@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)}
                   };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mockup method for listing all orders
    /// </summary>
    public static List<Order> ListOrders()
    {
        return new List<Order>()
                   {
                       new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail3@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)}, 
                       new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail5@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)},  
                       new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail6@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)}
                   };
    }
}
```

InterFace

```
public interface IMailSender
{
    void Send(string from, string to, string body);
}
sealed class NullMailSender : IMailSender
{
    void IMailSender.Send(string from, string to, string body)
    {

    }
}

sealed class SmtpMailSender : IMailSender
{
    void IMailSender.Send(string from, string to, string body)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
        mail.To.Add(to);
        mail.Body = body;
        smtp.Send(mail);

    }
}
```

This is the mail sending part, In the SendWelcome Email and SendComeback Email I've connected them to a text file with the body of the emails to avoid html in code.

```
public class SendingMail
{
    public List<string> Errors { get; } = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public IMailSender Sender { get; set; }

    public void SendWelcomeEmails()
    {
        var template = Resources.WelcomeEmailTemplate;
        Send(GetNewCustomers(), Resources.WelcomeEmailTemplate);
    }

    public void SendComeBackEmail()
    {
        var template = Resources.WelcomeEmailTemplate;
        var emailContent = String.Format(template);
        Send(GetCustomersWithoutRecentOrders(), Resources.ComeBackEmailTemplate);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Customer> GetNewCustomers()
    {
        var yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
        return Customers.Where(x => x.CreatedDateTime >= yesterday);
    }
    private IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersWithoutRecentOrders()
    {
        var oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);

        return Customers.Where(c => {
            var latestOrder = Orders
                .Where(o => o.CustomerEmail == c.Email)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDatetime)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return latestOrder != null
                && latestOrder.OrderDatetime < oneMonthAgo;
        });
    }

            private void Send(IEnumerable<Customer> customers, string body)
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            Send(customer, body);
    }
    private void Send(Customer customer, string body)
    {
        MailMessage message = GenerateMessage(customer, body);
        int NumberOfRetriesOnError = 2;
        int DelayOnError = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfRetriesOnError; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                Sender.Send(GenerateMessage);
                return;
            }
            catch (SmtpException e)
            {
                if (i < NumberOfRetriesOnError)
                    Thread.Sleep((i + 1) * DelayOnError);
                else
                    Errors.Add(e.Message + customer.Email); // Include customeremail
            }
        }
    }
    private MailMessage GenerateMessage(Customer customer, string body)
    {
        string subject = "...";
        string from = "...";
        string to = customer.Email;
        MailMessage retVal = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What was wrong with the other question? You could have edited it.

Comment: It got no response and felt dead, I've read it is okay to repost if no answer, was it too early to repost?

Comment: It was only 16 hours old... give it a few days at least ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Will do next time! :)

Comment: There is no overload of `SendComeBackEmail` which takes a string. What is `Sender`? Your `Main` doesn't seem to match the rest of your code.

Comment: This is tagged "unit-testing"... did you mean to include some unit tests too?

Comment: Sender is when I try to call the instance of the email interface called Sender

Comment: I meant the tag unit testing as making it easy to add unit tests later.

Comment: Have you considered using a library for sending emails...

Comment: Also, don't use Thread.Sleep for retry please

Comment: @Milney if you're not working with `async` code then `Thread.Sleep()` is perfectly fine when you do not need to support cancellation

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti And you would never want to use an email service in a multi-threaded environment??..... riiiiiight

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Or call this method from a UI? Which would cause it to freeze up.... It is just not perfectly fine, it is really bad practice. Use a proper retry pattern instead

Comment: In **this** case it's called from a dedicated console application. If it's called by a dedicated thread then you do not really need anything else. Is it `await`ed from GUI application? Then make it `async` and go with `Task.Delay()`. Unfortunately there isn't _one_ perfect way. Would you introduce, for example, a _retry timer_ when it's already called in a separate thread? What for? To call this code from UI thread is already a pretty bad idea, no matter the way you wait...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Do you write your code for a single use case only? You are doing programming wrong. You should use best practice at all times. Even though it is used form a console application now, it may be re-used later in another context... ever heard of code reuse? P.S. If you run it from a Task then it IS then async code!!!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - You are on a *Code Review* site, we are meant to be telling people how to make their  code better, not more brittle...

Comment: I'm smiling. You do programming for **actual** use case(s). If you try to cover everything before you need it then you're writing sub-optimal overengineered code. If you call it from a task (outside an async or awaitable method) then it's not different from a call queued in the pool. However such long running method may be well live on its own `Thread`. But, please, just search about this on SO, it has already been widely discussed

Comment: That's why on Code Review we need actual and not hypothetical code. Context matters

Comment: @Milney I see I forgot one important point, I agree that a _true_ e-mail sending agent will probably be designed in a completely different way (maybe using a queue of tasks where you also re-queue failed actions) but it's simply _too much_ for this toy application. Not to mention that when I needed to send few hundred (unimportant) e-mails...I wrote something pretty similar to this. Console application, enumerate through the list, retry if failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataLayer.ListCustomers()` should not be `static` for the *usual* reasons, not it's a mock used for testing purposes but you want to, ideally, switch between implementations without changing your model code. The same is true for `DataLayer.ListOrders()`. You can use a base abstract class or an interface. Also those methods shouldn't contain `List`, the data structure you use to accomodate them is an implementation detail which may (and should) change (you will see this when you will add a *true* ORM to your application). Class itself has a little bit *weird* name. Probably `Customer`, `Order` and `DataLayer` should be `sealed`.

In `SendWelcomeEmail()` (note that name is singular because you're sending a single e-mail) you're not *customizing* the template. The same is true for `SendComeBackEmail()` where you use it as parameter for `String.Format()` but you do not provide any...usable argument. You're also mixing welcome/come back content there...

For simplicity let me assume we're working with plain text templates.

Let's say you have a resource file with this text:

```
Welcome <CLIENT NAME>, please buy something from <COMPANY NAME>
```

Text between `<` and `>` is obviously a placeholder for something external to the template. It's now obvious that template is determined by `SendWelcomeEmail()` and `SendComeBackEmail()` but substitution must be performed by `Send()` because it's the one working with a specific customer (which we need to extract specific information).

Let's go with a first quick and very naive implementation using `String.Format()`. Use your template as formatting string:

```
Welcome {0}, please buy something from {1}
```

Code to use it:

```
private void SendWelcomeEmail()
{
    Send(GetNewCustomers(), Resources.WelcomeEmailTemplate);
}
```

And:

```
private void Send(Customer customer, string template)
{
    var body = String.Format(template, customer.FullName, "ACME Corporation");

    // ...
}
```

Now it works, it's not exactly an extensible approach and it's terrible when you will need to add anything else but...it's simple. Can we do better? Of course we can use and handmade text templating solution, we can use T4 text transformations or...use, for example, Handlebars.NET:

```
private void Send(Customer customer, string template)
{
        var compiledTemplate = 
        HandlebarsDotNet.Handlebars.Compile(template);
        var body = template(new {
        {
            CompanyName = "ACME Corporation",
            Customer = customer
        });

    // ...
}
```

Your text template will then be:

```
Welcome {{Customer.FullName}}, please buy something from {{CompanyName}}
```

That's much easier to extend, less error-prone and localization-friendly. We can do even better but we don't need to go that far now. Few more notes:

- `NumberOfRetriesOnError` and `DelayOnError` should be `private const` class fields, not local variables.
- `Send()` method has unneeded knowledge of the actual `IMailSender` implementation, it renders the interface itself half useless. Callers of `IMailSender.Send()` should have no knowledge at all about it! No error handling in that method and the message itself shouldn't be created inside `MailSender`.

What does it mean? `Send()` should probably be something like this (for now):

```
private void Send(IEnumerable<Customer> customers, string title, string template)
{
    if (Sender == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot send...");

    Errors.Clear();

    foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        string body = String.Format(template, customer.Name);
        Sender.Send(Errors, OurEmailAddress, customer.Email, title, body);
    }
}
```

And one implementation of `IMailSender.Send()`:

```
public void Send(IList<string> errors, string from, string to, string title, string body)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfRetriesOnError; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("yoursmtphost"))
            {
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
                mail.To.Add(to);
                mail.Body = body;

                smtp.Send(mail);
            }

            continue;
        }
        catch (SmtpException e)
        {
            if (i < NumberOfRetriesOnError)
                Thread.Sleep((i + 1) * DelayOnError);
            else
                errors.Add($"{to}: {e.Message}");
        }
    }

}
```

Also do not forget to check that `Orders` and `Customers` have a value before you use them (again you might throw `InvalidOperationException`). To pass a IList isn't an optimal solution but I think you may start with it, maybe in future you will need to create `Issue`, `IssueCollection` and pass a pass a reference to `IMailSender` but now I think it is only making things more complicate.

Comment: Another option is http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ for people coming from an ASP.Net MVC background.

Comment: @RobH absolutely!

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in a comment, your main method isn't really helpful to see how you intend to use this because it's using an undeclared `Sender` and `SendingMail` is the name of a type which makes it look like you're calling a static method. I assume you have some fields or properties with these names.

I'm mostly going to limit myself to your `SendingMail` class.

It has very confusing behaviour in at least 2 ways:

1. It stores errors as a public list
2. You have to know the implementation to create it correctly

For point 1, why are your `public` methods `void`? You want to know the results of sending the emails (that's why you've added the list). Why not return the list directly. You could even add a `MailSendingResult` class which encapsulates both successes and failures as well as other interesting data to be logged somewhere.

For point 2, consider this:

```
var mailer = new SendingMail();
mailer.SendComeBackEmail(); // Boom. Because `Sender` property will be `null`.
```

I haven't set the `IMailSender` so the class can't work. Add a constructor so the class can be instantiated correctly and obviously.

---

You have a bunch of unused code, for example:

```
var template = Resources.WelcomeEmailTemplate;
```

---

Try to avoid `DateTime.Now` and prefer `DateTime.UtcNow`. The former is local time which can jump around when there are things like Daylight Savings Transitions or even this sort of thing: [Samoa and Tokelau skip a day for dateline change](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-16351377).

---

Why have you implemented your interface explicitly? What benefit is that giving you?

## Edit

You have this:

```
sealed class NullMailSender : IMailSender
{
    void IMailSender.Send(string from, string to, string body)
    {

    }
}
```

When you could have this:

```
sealed class NullMailSender : IMailSender
{
    public void Send(string from, string to, string body)
    {

    }
}
```

The explicit interface implementation means you have to use an instance of the interface not the class. So with explicit interface implementation I can't do this:

```
NullMailSender sender = new NullMailSender();
sender.Send(null, null, null);
```

I would have to do this:

```
IMailSender sender = new NullMailSender();
sender.Send(null, null, null);
```

Comment: Will try to implement most of your suggestion, but I got confused at 
"I haven't set the IMailSender so the class can't work. Add a constructor so the class can be instantiated correctly and obviously." 

How do you mean with that? Also "Why have you implemented your interface explicitly?" I'm a bit new to implementing interfaces and thought that was the only way.

Comment: I've added some extra comments for you @JsonDork

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still unsure what you're meaning. And what did you mean with the constructor part, I'm assuming making a constructor of the interface in the sendingmail class? Or?

Comment: @JsonDork Create a constructor for `SendingEmail` class which populates the `Sender` property. If you add the code you're actually using to the question that I can compile, I can hopefully explain further. See here for interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @JsonDork - You need to show how you're creating your `SendingEmail` instance because at the moment, `Sender`, `Orders`, and `Customers` will all be null and your methods will throw `NullReferenceException`s.